# Disallowed Key Character

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-match

I've got a problem with CI Disallowed Key Character. When I am changing the core file `input.php`

```
exit('Disallowed Key Characters!! Clear Your Cookies.'.$str);
```

I get this string

```
Disallowed Key Characters!!.qqfilechunk|attraction-Pulaki-temple-not-far-from-Jimbaran-seminyak-kuta-leagian-nusa-dua-and-sanur-close-to-cheap-hotels-cheap-flight-with-air-asia-4-can-be-great-experience-to-come-to-bali-and-enj-_jpg|101077|2000000
```

I have changed the `pregmatch` to

```
preg_match("/^[#a-z0-9:_\/-|{}()%!=]+$/i", $str)
```

But I still get the `Disallowed Key Character` message.

Comment: which line you changed ?

Comment: why r you changing the core file ?, explain your need .

Comment: @ReNiShAR on function _clean_input_keys($str) at file input.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your regex:

- The `-` **must** go at the end of the character block, as usually this denotes a range of characters
- The reason your test string wasn't matching was because you're not allowing the `.` full stop character.

Change your regex to this:

```
/^[#a-z0-9:_\/|{}()%!=.-]+$/i
```

A [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) test page is available [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5E%5B%23a-z0-9%3A_%5C%2F%7C%7B%7D%28%29%25!%3D.-%5D%2B%24&input=.qqfilechunk%7Cattraction-Pulaki-temple-not-far-from-Jimbaran-seminyak-kuta-leagian-nusa-dua-and-sanur-close-to-cheap-hotels-cheap-flight-with-air-asia-4-can-be-great-experience-to-come-to-bali-and-enj-_jpg%7C101077%7C2000000).

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)
```

it will avoid the error.

check your input tag also any missing quotes or something:

in this case the error occurs:

```
<input type="text" name="nam value=" " />
```

because i just miss the closing quotes of name tag !

check for these type of errors....

Comment: I've been trying your suggestion and it's not work. Still got the error

Comment: chk your input tags.. i updated my answer,,, chk it.